# Telegram Bot API token - unauthorized errors - do they expire?

Tags: typescript, telegram-bot, react-typescript, hubot

We've been experiencing "unauthorized" errors with our bots lately and I can't understand why it could happen besides the above title. Do Telegram Bot API tokens expire and need to be refreshed? I read the docs and couldn't find anything to suggest they do.

Thanks for any insight into this!

Comment: was it working before?

Comment: @InjamulMohammadMollah I believe so - I inherited the project but users reported making bots and using them but not using them for a year or so. One user had their bot mysteriously vanish as well as if Telegram deleted it.

Comment: agreed. had bot erlier, but later bot was deleted. used as multi-user rarely notifier.